# EXC_BAD_ACCESS - NSString out of scope

Tags: crash, nsstring, exc-bad-access

The app I am working on is a trivia quiz.
If you get the answer wrong, it shows you the correct answer.

The correct answer is stored in a string like so:

```
correctAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1/100"];
```

When it's time to show the answer to the user, I set the label's text to the correct answer:

```
whatsRight.text = correctAnswer;
```

This works 99% of the time.
BUT - occasionally I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS terminating the app and the correctAnswer string is said to be "out of scope." This seems to always happen on the same question in my app - the one shown above where the correctAnswer is 1/100. It doesn't always crash the app with EXC_BAD_ACCESS though. Lots of times it works perfectly fine, displays the answer on screen, and the app continues on. Occasionally it crashes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS is usually caused by trying to access an object that has been released. What is your retain policy on correctAnswer? Also, probably unrelated, but why use stringWithFormat, when you have no format? Just try correctAnswer = @"1/100".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try retaining correctAnswer via [correctAnswer retain]. My thought is that the correctAnswer object may be an autorelease object and since your not retaining it, it's getting released.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it. Strange when you need / don't need to retain an object. As I said, this worked without error the majority of the time, and I hadn't gotten a crash in all my device testing, but every now and then in the simulator it was apparently getting released and causing my error...

Comment: quoted everywhere "retain" but added an additional [variablename retain] after the assignment :) now everything works perfectly! thank you